# Why am I suddenly unable to use the terminal in any JetBrains IDE?

Tags: powershell, intellij-idea, terminal, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I went to use my terminal in JetBrains WebStorm IDE, and received this error:

```text
Cannot open Local Terminal 
Failed to start [powershell.exe] in C:\Users\schmidtrj\WebstormProjects\React Translator
See IDE log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) for the details.
```

The log: https://pastebin.com/aQ6gPZc0

All other JetBrains IDEs give the same issue. The shell path in each of the IDEs terminal settings is `powershell.exe` - what it was set to by default - and has worked up until now.

I have tried changing the shell to the absolute path of it (`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`). This let me use the terminal, but prevented me from using things like nodejs / running any scripts in my program. Moreover, that was not always necessary for the terminal to run, and must not be the problem.

Directories in my systems environment variable `Path`:

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
> C:\Windows
> C:\Windows\System32
> C:\Windows\System32\Wbem

I was able to execute `powershell` when going to the directory of my programs through command prompt, so I don't understand where my issue is. Appreciate any feedback on this, as I have been unable to find a sufficient solution from other posts made that are relevant to this.

Comment: Odd. 1) What's your IDE version? 2) The log states the similar error for `wmic` as well (used to detect Windows Defender status/settings) so it's not just this. 3) Have you tried the magic -- rebooting the PC? 4) Can you use `cmd.exe` as a terminal? 5) If not -- even if full path is used? 6) When the terminal works (when using the full path) -- check what `PATH` env var has. In CMD it's as simple as `PATH` (the actual command), for PowerShell try `$Env:Path.Split(";")`

Comment: 7) What's your Terminal settings in the IDE (`Settings | Tools | Terminal`). What options you have ticked there? 8) Try disabling `terminal.use.conpty.on.windows` in `Help->Find Action->Registry` (not sure if restart is needed).

Comment: Still opened tickets I have found 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-278224 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-283884